# Navigating back to a UIKit View from SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I am working on refactoring the sign-up and I am having an issue with navigating back to a UIKit view named `WelcomeViewController()` from a SwiftUI view named `SignUpView()`.

Here is the code snippet used to take the user from `WelcomeViewController()` to `SignUpView()` in `WelcomeViewController.Swift`:

```
@objc private func startSignUpFlow() {
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SignUpView(signupState: signupState))
        navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
    }
```

Here is the code for `SignUpView()`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignUpView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var phoneNumber = ""
    @State private var isNavigatingToInterests = false
    @State private var coordinator: Coordinator?
    @ObservedObject var signupState: SignupState
    
    var isContinueButtonEnabled: Bool {
        !name.isEmpty &&
        !email.isEmpty && CaseSensitivity.isValidEmail(email) &&
        !username.isEmpty && CaseSensitivity.isValidUsername(username) &&
        !password.isEmpty && CaseSensitivity.isValidPassword(password) &&
        !phoneNumber.isEmpty && CaseSensitivity.isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("uSTADIUM")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 191, height: 45)
                    .padding(.top, -64)
                ZStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Personal Information")
                                .font(
                                    Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 18)
                                        .weight(.bold)
                                )
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.12, green: 0.12, blue: 0.12))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Step 1")
                                .font(Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 14))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.68, blue: 1))
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                        
                        TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your name", text: $name, isValid: true)
                        
                        TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your email", text: $email, isValid: CaseSensitivity.isValidEmail(email))
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                        
                        TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your username", text: $username, isValid: CaseSensitivity.isValidUsername(username))
                        
                        TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter your password", text: $password, isValid: CaseSensitivity.isValidPassword(password))
                        
                        TextFieldValidity(placeholder: "Enter phone number", text: $phoneNumber, isValid: CaseSensitivity.isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber))
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: PickYourInterestsView(signupState: signupState), isActive: $isNavigatingToInterests) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            if isContinueButtonEnabled {
                                let accountData = AccountSignup(email: email, username: username, password: password)
                                
                                AuthService.shared.signup(data: accountData) { result, error in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    } else if let result = result {
                                        print("SignUp Successful!")
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                isNavigatingToInterests = true
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Continue")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 18))
                                .padding()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(isContinueButtonEnabled ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .disabled(!isContinueButtonEnabled)
                    }
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: CustomBackButton(action: {
                        coordinator?.navBackToWelcome()
                    }))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.top, 60) // Adjust the top padding as needed
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    .background {
                        Color.white
                            .cornerRadius(16)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 6)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                    .inset(by: 0.5)
                                    .stroke(Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 1), lineWidth: 1)
                            )
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .onAppear {
                    coordinator = Coordinator()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SignUpView {
    class Coordinator {
        weak var welcomeViewController: WelcomeViewController?

        init() {
            if let welcomeViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? WelcomeViewController {
                print("Found WelcomeViewController")
                self.welcomeViewController = welcomeViewController
            } else {
                print("Error: View Controller not found")
            }
        }

        func navBackToWelcome() {
            print("This function is being called.")
            welcomeViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomBackButton: View {
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            action()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.square.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(12)
        }
    }
}
```

The Coordinator class accepts a reference to `WelcomeViewController()` directly, which is then passed in onAppear. However, the error message fro the init() function in the Coordinator class is shown, and the button does not work as intended. What should be done to have the button work?

Comment: Is your app built with UIKit or SwiftUI? (Is the `@main` attribute placed in `AppDelegate` or in your main view -probably called `ContentView`-?
Could you provide simple example to evaluate?

Comment: The app is built mainly in UIKit however we are refactoring certain parts like the sign up into SwiftUI. The ```@main``` attribute is placed in ```AppDelegate```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tot dismiss back to the `WelcomeViewController` using the [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss/) environment variable should work just fine.

```swift
struct FirstView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Dismiss me") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a bunch